Movie about a mindcontrolling monster on earth and nice human-like aliens trying to stop it
I only have a few remembrances of this movie I watched when I was like 7... Could anyone help me figure the title ?
All I can remember is that the bad guy is some kind of monster that's able to telepathically force humans to do what he wants. 
There's a scene, I guess at the beginning, where it is held prisoner in an alien spaceship (the aliens might be humans, but not from earth, I don't remember). The entire crew wears a helmet to prevent being mind-controlled, but one guy forgets his or something, And the big monster go hide and make a mess on earth. Well, more like New-York, or another big city of America.
All I can remember after that is a scene is the sewers where the hero, a random citizen, take the laser gun from the beautiful alien girl - who's here to kill the beast but got her ass kicked - and fire the thing until the monster is forced to flee somewhere else. 
That's pretty much it. After that the girl tells the hero that the gun needs some time to reload before it can shoot again.
I watched the movie in the middle of the 90's, so I guess it's a pretty ancient one. It has been in my head for years, please help.

There aren't any anti-mind-control helmets, but otherwise it sounds like the 1988 miniseries Something is Out There, with Joe Cortese and Maryam d'Abo.  The full movie is available in two parts on Youtube, and the sewer scene is near the end of part one.

Wow, you are my hero... Thank you !
